# Update a record in a database using WCF Data Services

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to use WCF Data Services and I'm a little confused about where I'm wrong in trying to update a record, based on a key field value.
My simplified approach, which doesn't work:

```
 MydbEntities context = new MydbEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:53051/Services/MydbService.svc"));
 MyEntity avt = context.MyTable.Where(p => p.EntID == "val1").FirstOrDefault();
 avt.FieldToEdit = 1;
 context.UpdateObject(avt);
 context.BeginSaveChanges(OnChangesSaved, context);
 ...
 private void OnChangesSaved(IAsyncResult result)
 {            
     MessageBox.Show("seems ok");//I'm getting this message, but, in fact, data in db remains unchanged
 }
```

Please, tell me, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem. It was trivial (I feel like an idiot), there was no writing access rights set in the service initializer. There was the following:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
      ...
}
```

after I changed it to:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
```

all started to work as expected.
And, of course, such a broad access rule I set only for testing purposes. Later it should be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnChangesSaved handler, you need to call `context.EndSaveChanges(result)`.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903956%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has some sample code that illustrates the whole process.

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but the problem is, when trying to call that, I get a runtime error: `An error occurred while processing this request.`